# android web scraping behind a secure login

Tags: java, android

I've been racking my brain about this for a while, I've managed to send a post request to a `https` based login form using the android sdk, specifically the `org.apache.http library`.

All seems well in that the response i get back from the server is 200 OK.

However, I can't figure out how to then scrape the page behind the login. The apache library seems geared towards server `requests/repsonses` so the question is how can i get the actual `html` page back using the `android sdk`?

Example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you're making the request and getting a response, but you're trying to figure out how to get the "body" of the response?

Answer (score 1):

Examples of using HttpClient, including the use of ResponseHandler, can be found at:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html